# SQL Query - c# database connection (DataGrid)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get information from 2 tables with a SQL query..

```
SELECT Num_of_icon, ID_Radar, ID_Observer,
       Longitude_Impact_point, Latitude_Impact_point,
       Longitude_Impact_point_By_Cutting, Latitude_Impact_point_By_Cutting,
       Deviation_In_Meters,
       Longitude_Deviation, Latitude_Deviation,
       Longitude, Latitude, Azimuth
FROM ShowTable, Observer
ORDER BY Num_of_icon ASC
```

`Num_of_icon` is a key in one table.
`ID_Observer` is a key in the second table **and** a field in the first table.

The error is:

> The field 'ID_Observer' should be show in more than one table.

I dont understand what this error is about.. I know that `ID_Observer` is showing more than one table, that's why I have a connection between the tables...

Answer (score 1):

You have to qualify a column with `tablename.columnname` if a column exists in two tables. You also have to link both tables via `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Num_of_icon, 
       ID_Radar, 
       SHowTable.ID_Observer, --<<< HERE
       Longitude_Impact_point, 
       Latitude_Impact_point, 
       Longitude_Impact_point_By_Cutting, 
       Latitude_Impact_point_By_Cutting, 
       Deviation_In_Meters, 
       Longitude_Deviation, 
       Latitude_Deviation, 
       Longitude, 
       Latitude, 
       Azimuth 
FROM   ShowTable 
INNER JOIN Observer 
    ON ShowTabl.ID_Observer = Observer.ID_Observer  --<<< and HERE
ORDER  BY Num_of_icon ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The query processor does not know which of the `ID_Observer` fields it should take (and it doesn't make an effort to determine whether they will always be the same value regardless of which table it takes it from). So you'll have to specify this, ie the following will take the `ID_Observer` value from the `Observer` table:

```
"SELECT Num_of_icon,ID_Radar,Observer.ID_Observer,Longitude_Impact_point..."
```